# Merge lines to polylines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polyline-creation

I've migrated some 50,000 buildings from some crappy CAD environment into an SDE database. The problem is that the majority of the buildings is represented as lines, not polylines I.e. every wall is a single line feature.

Now I need to merge these features into polylines. I've been thinking about some ways to do this: check geometry, create topology rules, buffer and merge but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The buildings doesn't have a unique ID and some of them are adjacent to other buildings which makes it a bit harder.

Is there a best practice for these kinds of operations?

Comment: Have you tried [Snap geoprocessing tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/snapping-multiple-features-together.htm) ("This tool is useful for cleaning up features that were not digitized using snapping or were imported from another format, such as CAD.") and/or [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm)?

Comment: Well the end points are connected but they need to be merged into single features

Comment: Then use dissolve

Comment: Sure but if i run dissolve on the entire dataset the result will be one single feature consisting of thousands of building.

Comment: So all Buildings overlap? If not, just uncheck "Create multipart features". Add a screenshot to your question

Comment: Actually that worked, it was that simple.. using unsplit lines and create multipart features. Now all the attributes has to be transferred to the new feature class.

Comment: Use Spatial Join

Comment: Great thanks, all done!

Answer (score 2):

1. [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/h-how-dissolve-data-management-works.htm)
2. [Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) attributes from the split lines to the dissolved ones.